# Difference between activity_main.xml and fragment_main_dummy.xml?

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, android-fragments

Why is there a `dummy` layout file created in each new Android app in Eclipse? I don't know why it's there and can't find an explanation for it.

There is the `activity_main.xml` and then there is the `fragment_main_dummy.xml` file. Which one is the `main` one that I should dump my controls on?

[image]

Comment: could you explain you steps of creating new Project.

Comment: @Pratik, I created a tab based app where you slide left or right to switch between tabs.

Comment: You can see my updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [fragment_main_dummy.xml](http://developer.android.com/samples/HorizontalPaging/res/layout/fragment_main_dummy.html)

There is an sample of whole project.

This file is used as layout of the fragment.

For more about [**Fragment**](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html), you can see this [**Example**](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/app/fragment/android-fragments-example/)

Comment: If I understand correctly, each "tab page" is a fragment that gets added to activity_main.xml. so basically activity_main is just a holder for all the different fragments/pages?

Comment: @user-12506 Yes, create demo example for more understand about fragment.

Comment: Thanks guys for your help :) I'm not sure which answer to accept now since they both are correct.

Answer (score 1):

These two file created which is basic template provided by the android for the `Fragments`. As you create a project as Fragment project it will add the two layout files one will be the simple file and other will contain the `Fragment`.

Creates a new master/detail flow, allowing users to view a collection of objects as well as details for each object. This flow is presented using two columns on tablet-size screens and one column on handsets and smaller screens. The template creates activities, a master fragment, and a detail fragment.

Its a templates in android in which on it master file and another is a detail fragment layout.

From that the `activity_main.xml` will be always main file. And the `fragment_main_dummy.xml` is the details fragment file layout.